# Looking for a linear time implementation of Salvador's L-Method for determining the number of clusters

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, linear-regression, hierarchical-clustering

The original paper is here http://cs.fit.edu/~pkc/papers/ictai04salvador.pdf

The L-method discovered by Stan Salvador and Philip Chan is for "Determining the number of clusters in hierarchical clustering algorithms"

The algorithm is described in the paper, and **said clearly to have "linear time complexity."**

The main idea of the algorithm is:

Given an evaluation graph (x - number of clusters to be merged, y - merge distance)

Given **b** = number of items to be clustered

**Let RMSEC(c) = (c-1) / (b-1) * RMSE(Lc) + (b - c) / (b - 1) * RMSE(Rc)**

Note :

- **RMSE** is a root mean squared error of a best fit line.
- **RMSE(Lc)** is RMSE given x[1, c], y[1, c] -- the left part of the evaluation graph
- **RMSE(Rc)** is RMSE given x[c+1, b-1], y[c+1, b-1] -- the right part of the evaluation graph

Goal: **Find a C that minimizes RMSEC(c)**

To calculate its time complexity, I assume

- Line of best fit -- O(b)
- Loop over c -- O(b)

Cumulatively, I can not come up with the linear time implementation of this algorithm.

Does anyone have any idea to improve this ? Is it possible to calculate the line of best fit incrementally to attain O(N) overall ? Or any workaround ?

Comment: I've skimmed the paper, and concluded that its claims of being "faster" (the word "linear" doesn't appear in any description of time complexity) are dicey.  I think the most that could be said is that it requires a linear number of Least Squares problems to be solved -- one per value of the breakpoint c.  It certainly can't be linear time in the number of points *overall*, since it requires solving at least 2 Least Squares problems, which to the best of my knowledge requires at least one matrix multiplication, and the best algorithm for doing that is about O(n^2.7).

Comment: you gave some confidence, thanks :D